# Why are these divs not side by side when positioned using float inside pre element?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I wonder why float behaves differently when used within `<pre>` element.

Example is taken from https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-web-dev-v3/lessons/css/layout-css

```css
.ex-box {
  border: 3px solid #aaa;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.ex-box:last-of-type {
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <div class="ex-box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="ex-box">Box 2</div>
</pre>
```

**I'm aware that using float for positioning is obsolete and there are better alternatives like flex or grid**

Comment: The `<pre>` element is preserving the white space in your code. Remove the white space between your divs and they line up.

Comment: @j08691 yes, it seems like it. Moving the second div to the same line or chaning `line-height` to `0` fixes the problem

Comment: `font-size: 0` on the pre also will accomplish the same thing. Typical solutions when dealing with vertical alignment of inline elements.